# Silverlight: How to use a converter with an ItemsControl?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, xaml

I have an `ItemsControl` whose `ItemsSource` is bound to a list of ints IDs. A converter uses the IDs to look up the name that should be displayed to the user. How can I do this in XAML? Here is what I have so far, but it doesn't work:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Topics}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FallbackValue='topic name', Converter={StaticResource topicToStrConverter}}" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                    <Button>
                        <Image Source="/PlumPudding;component/Images/appbar.cancel.rest.png" />
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Really, what I want as an argument to the converter is the entire item that is being displayed in the template - not a property of that item. What is the syntax for this?

I'm using Silverlight 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if Topics is List, then what you have is correct.

However, if Topics is List, and Id is a property of the Topic class, you will need to use "Path=Id".  So: {Binding FallbakcValue='Bla', Path=Id, Converter={StaticResource yourConverter}

To answer you second question:
*"what I want as an argument to the converter is the entire item that is being displayed in the template - not a property of that item"*

This syntax you are using will pass the entire object in the List, so in your case an int is passed to the converter.  Again, if it is a list, then the Topic object is passed to the converter.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right to my opinion..

It seems that problem in 'converter'. Try to debug code of topicToStrConverter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the DataContext for the items control or for one of it's parents. If you don't do this there is no context for the binding.